# UrlFetchApp zip file

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets, zip

I'm trying to fetch a zip file with the code below:

```
  var options = {
    'method' :'get',
    'validateHttpsCertificates' : false,
    'escaping': true
  };
  var url = "https://www.propertypriceregister.ie/website/npsra/ppr/npsra-ppr.nsf/Downloads/PPR-ALL.zip/$FILE/PPR-ALL.zip" 
  var zipblob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getBlob(); 
  var unzipblob = Utilities.unzip(zipblob);
```

and getting the error `Address unavailable: https://www.propertypriceregister.ie/website/npsra/ppr/npsra-ppr.nsf/Downloads/PPR-ALL.zip/$FILE/PPR-ALL.zip`

I would normally download the file using wget - e.g.

```
wget --no-check-certificate 'https://www.propertypriceregister.ie/website/npsra/ppr/npsra-ppr.nsf/Downloads/PPR-ALL.zip/$FILE/PPR-ALL.zip'
```

and that works fine - the unzipped file is a csv.

Tried different values for options in the apps script, with `escaping=false` etc. without much success.

I would much appreciate some help! Thanks!

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Is there anything that I can do for your question? If my answer was not useful for your situation. I have to apologize and modify it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. I would like to think of about the solution.

Comment: The solution below throws the exact same error message. I think the culprit may be in that `$FILE` in the URL

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. When I run this modified script in my Google account, the zip file can be extracted. The url is ``https://www.propertypriceregister.ie/website/npsra/ppr/npsra-ppr.nsf/Downloads/PPR-ALL.zip/$FILE/PPR-ALL.zip``. The filename, mimeType and file size of the extracted file are ``PPR-ALL.csv``, ``text/csv`` and ``49,655,119`` bytes. If this information is correct, can you confirm the script and URL and try it again? If the same error occurs, I worry about the access limitation.

Answer (score 1):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- From your wget sample command, in your case, I thought that `options` is not required.
- When the zip file is downloaded, it is found that the mimeType is `application/x-zip` from the response header. In the case of `Utilities.unzip()`, the mimeType is required to be modified to `application/zip`.

  - In this case, I used `setContentTypeFromExtension()`, because the file has the filename including the extension.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
var url = "https://www.propertypriceregister.ie/website/npsra/ppr/npsra-ppr.nsf/Downloads/PPR-ALL.zip/$FILE/PPR-ALL.zip" 
var zipblob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob(); // Modified
zipblob.setContentTypeFromExtension(); // Added
var unzipblob = Utilities.unzip(zipblob);
```

#### Reference:

- [setContentTypeFromExtension()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#setContentTypeFromExtension())